# A question on arithmetic means

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\lbrace a_i \colon i=1\ldots n \rbrace$ be a set of $n$ integers greater than 1. Let $k$ be a positive integer. 
Is it true that:

> $(\text{mean}(a_i))^k \leq \text{mean}(a_i^k)$

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are basically asking whether
$$\left(\frac{a_1+\dots+a_n}n\right)^k \le \frac{a_1^k+\dots+\dots a_n^k}n.$$

This is true if the function $f(x)=x^k$ is convex, it is the simplest form of [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).

The function $x^k$ is convex for $k\ge 1$, so the above is true for any positive integer. (And it is not important whether $a_i$'s are integers.)

Note that for $k=2$ you get
$$\left(\frac{a_1+\dots+a_n}n\right)^2 \le \frac{a_1^2+\dots+\dots a_n^2}n$$
$$\frac{a_1+\dots+a_n}n \le \sqrt{\frac{a_1^2+\dots+\dots a_n^2}n}$$

This  is the inequality between arithmetic and quadratic mean, see e.g. [AoPS](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Jensen%27s_Inequality) and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Generalized_mean_inequality).